# Why do derived classes need to use a base class constructor

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, constructor

The title explains it all I believe.

In C#, I am now aware that regardless, constructors in derived classes will call a base class constructor whether it is an explicit call or an implicit default constructor. My question is why? I think it's because the derived class needs to create an object of the base class but why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I think it's because the derived class needs to create an object of the base class but why?

An instance of a derived class *is* an instance of the base class. If you have a rule for what must happen when you construct an Animal, and you're constructing a Giraffe, then *somehow* you have to execute the rule for constructing an Animal. In C# that mechanism is "call a base class constructor".

Answer (score 9):

A derived class is the base class plus extra things the derived class adds.

You still need some code that initializes the base class portion so you can add your extra parts on top. The call to the base constructor is where that initialization happens.

Answer (score 1):

let's say the car is your abstract class and bmw,mazda,jeep are your driven classes.
you have fields: Name , Model,..
you have constroctor: car(),car(string model)

in car class, then when compiler doing memory allocation for object need to read abstract constructor to be aware of Name, Model.
this will call the default constructor. but you can use base("z4") to force calling overridden constructor in the abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

As Scott Chamberlain said the derived class is something (plus some more features).

Of course an object can have behaviors in the constructor.

Anyway if you don't need to inherit them, you should structure your code in the right way,

you should leave base constructor empty, depends on your specific needs